# Python - Как будет выглядеть subprocess.call для выражения echo "name" > filename.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Как будет выглядеть `subprocess.call` для выражения:

```
echo "name" > filename.txt
```

`subprocess.call("echo 'name' > " + filename, shell=True)` не срабатывает.
Значит я вбиваю, что-то не так. Что нужно исправить?

Comment: Марина, добрый день! А напишите, пожалуйста. сюда текст ошибки, которвый вы получаете. Давайте вместе разберемся!

Comment: У меня срабатывает.